# Execute file from Powershell without getting "Do you want to run this file?" dialog

Tags: powershell

I'm looping through .exe files in a directory and extracting the .msp files.
Ideally it would happen silently.

This batch file command works perfectly.

```
for %%g in ("C:\test\"*.exe) do %%g /quiet /extract:"C:\test"
```

This powershell script almost gets it done.

```
$exeFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $directory -recurse -include *.exe
foreach($file in $exeFiles) 
{ 
    $appArgs = '/quiet /extract:"' + $directory + '"'
    Start-Process $exeFiles $appArgs -PassThru | Wait-Process
}
```

However, Windows 7 throws up the "Do you want to run this file?" dialog.
How do I make the powershell truly silent?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem but you're calling Start-Process on the $exeFiles variable rather than

```
for ($file in $exeFiles)
{
    start-process $file (...etc)
}
```

You're also passing the args as a string so i suspect they're not getting through to the exe.  if you pass arguments to start-process they must be in the form of an array, one string per element in the array.  Not only that, but powershell uses $args and it appears to be immutable, so you need a different variable name:

So your code should look more like this:

```
$directory = "C:\test"
$exeFiles = Get-ChildItem -path $directory -recurse -include *.exe
foreach($file in $exefiles) 
{ 
    $myArgs = '/quiet', ('/extract:"' + $directory + '"')
    Start-Process $file $myArgs -PassThru | Wait-Process
}
```

Comment: Hi calavera.  Thanks for the response.  The variable names were typos while trying to simplify the code for the question.  They've been fixed.  Thanks.
As far as passing the arguments as a string, it actually works perfectly.  I think the problem I'm having is a security issue when trying to extract a file on a network drive.  Looking into it further now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is trust relationship between the machine and the resource its getting the file from. if both machines belong to the same domain, you should not be getting this dialog.
if they are not in a domain (ie intrernet or extranet) go to:Control Panel-> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites
 click "add", type in the resource you want to trust

file://servername.domainname

click OK, and try again.
Personally I'm trying to do this via WMI, anyone know how?